# Leaving out particles before adjectives/verbs?

Tags: grammar, particles

I haven't really read any guides on Japanese grammar (except occasionally looking up pages of Tae Kim's when I need something explained), so I became quite confused when I saw things on Twitter like これすごい (instead of something like これ**は**すごい). I also noticed people seem to do the same thing with verbs, like saying アニメ見た instead of アニメ**を**見た (that's probably a bad example, but it's the first thing I could come up with).

So what is up with this? Is there some sort of pattern behind it I can follow? At first I thought it was something done in a casual setting (like a Tweet), but I feel like I've seen the same thing done in more polite Japanese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquialism often amounts to simplify things by contracting or entirely omitting supposed-to-be-easily-understood elements. Thus those particles are the victims of such tendency. It is not recommended to follow that in formal documents. Does this make sense?

Comment: It makes sense. I mostly wanted to know if what I was seeing was just pure colloquialism or an actual part of Japanese grammar. In English we have plenty of localized dialects where we leave out stuff, but it doesn't really translate into the written language.